# Dropdown clipped by the sidebar panel when using a scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, r, twitter-bootstrap-3, shiny

I'm using a scrollbar for the sidebar in a shiny app, simply with the help of the css `height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;`. Then a problem occurs if I use a `shinyWidgets::dropdown` in the sidebar: if the dropdown panel is larger than the sidebar panel, then it is clipped by the sidebar panel (see the attached gif).

Perhaps I have a JavaScript solution but not a simple one and I'm working in collaboration with some colleagues who are not comfortable with JavaScript and who don't like when I use JavaScript (this complicates the maintenance of the app). Is there a CSS solution? Or a *simple* JavaScript solution ?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      style = "height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;", 
      sliderInput("bins", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      dropdown(
        tags$h1("A very large dropdown"),
        label = "Open me!",
        width = "500px"
      ),
      sliderInput("bins2", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins3", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins4", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins5", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins6", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins7", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins8", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins9", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins10", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins11", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins12", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins13", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins14", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins15", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30),
      br(),
      sliderInput("bins16", "Number of bins:", min = 1, max = 50, value = 30)
    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    x    <- faithful[, 2] 
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

---

## EDIT

Here is a JavaScript solution:

```
js <- '
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[id^=sw-content-]").on("shown", function(){
    $(".sidebar").css({"overflow-y": "visible"});
  }).on("hidden", function(){
    $(".sidebar").css({"overflow-y": "auto"});
  });
});
'
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(js)),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      class = "sidebar",
      style = "height: 90vh; overflow-y: auto;", 
      .......
```

But I'm not sure it causes no other issues. If the dropdown has a large height, we cannot scroll anymore with this solution.

---

## Edit 2

Hmm... finally, maybe the JS solution is fine. We can scroll a heighty dropdown panel with the main scrollbar:

[image]

Comment: is there possible to have fix width for 'A very large dropdown' ?